# A version of this question should exist- but I don't know how to improve on the closed one

Tags: discussion

A while ago, I saw this question from another user:

[How would one deal with a cyclically recursive relation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210178/how-would-one-deal-with-a-cyclically-recursive-relation/)

To me, it not only was clear what was being asked, but it's also a useful question. It describes a specific, practical problem that you can often run into when dealing with algorithms relating to recursive relations. It also has a simple, general solution, which- although relatively obvious- isn't trivial.

Unfortunately, after a flurry of confusion in the comments, it got closed. One of the close-voters, and the person arguing most strenuously for it to be closed in the comments posted this, which is just plain wrong:

> I see two options: Either there are base cases (in both directions), or OP has misunderstood the problem and a correct definition of foo(n) isn't actually of the form described in the question.

The OP didn't seem interested in rehabilitating the question, so I gave it a thorough edit to try to make it as clear as possible but it didn't reach the reopen quota (IIRC it got up to 4).

Now, I don't mind so much whether this *particular* question remains closed or open, but since to me the underlying problem and solution seem valuable, I would like *some* non-closed version of it to exist. I would happily create and self-answer another one, but the problem is now that I've edited this one, I can't think of any significant further improvement I can make on it. Just rewording the same question as a new one seems like it would be trying to skirt the site's rules, but there's also nothing more I can reasonably do to help get the original reopened.

Comment: Well the question was reopened, I assume due to this meta post. Thanks to the voters.